# How can I create a google-analytics profile that will include stuff that matches ANY (not ALL) of my filters?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a test profile in my google analytics account, and ultimately I'd like that profile to include all of the following:

1. all requests to the test.mydomain.com subdomain
2. all requests that include "test.mydomain.com" somewhere in the URI
3. all events that include "test.mydomain.com" somewhere in the category

I had originally tried creating 3 filters on that profile (one for each of the above), but it appears that google-analytics profiles only include things that match ALL filters.

I tried using an advanced filter to combine the above 3 items together into one field, so that I could then just search that field using a regex, but I'm not having much luck... Here's what I have so far:

Filter 1:
[image]
which should result in "|test|test" being placed into Custom Field 1 (assuming I had "test.mydomain.com" somewhere in the event category and "test.mydomain.com" as the Hostname)

Filter 2:
[image]
which should result in "|test|test|test|" being placed into Custom Field 2 (assuming I had "test.mydomain.com" somewhere in the Request URI).

Filter 3:
[image]
which should make it so my profile includes all items where "|test|" appears somewhere in Custom Field 2.

Unfortunately, that's not working, as my test profile is always empty.  My "include everything" profile is showing that my requests *are* coming through and that the *do* include "test.mydomain.com".  I've tried other variations of the above filters, such as setting my advanced-filter regular expressions to ".*", so that they simply concatenate the full Category, Hostname, and Request URI together into Custom Field 2 and then adjusting filter 3 accordingly, but still nothing comes through on that profile. I understand that changes made to profiles can sometimes take a couple of hours to start showing up (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638635?hl=en), but my test filters have been set up for days, so Google should have applied them by now.

Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong? Am I just misunderstanding how the advanced filter works?

Does anyone know of a way to inspect the value of "Custom Field 1" and/or "Custom Field 2" so I can see if those are being built correctly?

Comment: I think your best bet here is to figure out how Google Analytics works on another forum.  Then once you get that down, get some good source examples against which your regexes will be parsing, and just ask the question here on the most efficient way to parse those examples with regex, if that's truly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The technique that I outlined in my original question, or the technique suggested by Andy should work fine.  The problem in my specific example is that google-analytics filters do not have full support for regular expressions.  In particular, they do not support the positive lookahead in my example.  The other part of my issue was that I sometimes wasn't waiting long enough before testing my profile changes (google can sometimes take a few hours before applying the changes).

To see what regex options google does support, see https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en.  I originally thought that page was a "getting started with regular expressions" page, but, apparently, that might be *all* of the regex language that google supports.

If you are unsure if there are parts of your regex that google doesn't support, you can test it on the google-analytics site directly, and in realtime on live data (without waiting for google to apply your profile changes), by navigating to **Content > Site Content > All Pages** in your Profile, then click on "Advanced" at the top of the "Primary Dimension" table, then change the match type to "Matching RegExp" (see https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2936903?hl=en).  There you can enter in your regex, and if google doesn't support part of your regex, it will tell you *immediately* when you click "Apply" (not sure why they don't include that regex validation on their profile filter page...). You will also be able to see it immediately filter the content of that table.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with 4 filters (3 advanced, 1 include).  If any of the requirements are satisfied, write "ok" in one of the custom fields.  Then do an include on that custom field that matches "ok".

filter 1 - advanced
field a - hostname
extract a - test.mydomain.com
output to - custom field 1
constructor - ok

Use the above concept for the remaining 2 conditions.  Then do an include on custom field 1 = ok

Comment: Thanks for the response, Andy. That's an interesting suggestion. I'm not sure why my original attempt, above, didn't work... but I've set up a few profiles to test your suggestion out. They aren't working yet, but sometimes google is slow at applying changes. I'll update this once I see how it goes.